# custom web control html render

Tags: c#, umbraco

This is my code , i created my custum radiobuttonlist. And it works but.. take a look at the code guys. Im using umbraco and C#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using umbraco;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;
using System.Web.Security;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;
using System.Collections;

namespace RadioButtonList
{

    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:RadioButtonList runat=server></{0}:RadioButtonList>")]
    public class RadioButtonList : System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]

        private void populate()

    {
        foreach (umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem d in umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.getTopMostItems)
        {
            if (d.hasChildren)
            {
                foreach (umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem d1 in d.Children)
                {
                    if (d1.hasChildren)
                    {
                        if (d1.Value(1) == "Target Groups")
                        {
                            SortedList list = new SortedList();
                            foreach (umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem d2 in d1.Children)
                            {
                                string translation;
                                int lang = umbraco.library.GetCurrentDomains(umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().Id)[0].Language.id;
                                translation = "";
                                translation = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem(d2.key).Value(lang);

                                list.Add(translation, d2.key);



                            }
                            this.DataSource = list;
                            this.DataValueField = "value";
                            this.DataTextField = "key";
                            this.DataBind();


                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }


        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)

        {

            base.OnPreRender(e);

            populate();

        }

    }
```

It works i can get the new web control but i want to "control" the render html. My RadioButtonList renders a span but i dont want it cause it create some issues. I already tryed this

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
RenderContents(writer);
}
```

But when i use this my radiobuttonlist disappears and i cant see it anymore. I really need help cause im new to this and its my 1st time using custum server controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [RepeatLayout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it. Anything but Flow will get rid of the span, but it depends what you want to replace it with as to what value you want.